# Issue with convolution kernels that add up to zero

Tags: c++, image-processing, sfml

I'm making an image editing program in c++ using sfml and tried to add image filters using:

```
int clamp(int value, int min, int max)
{
    if (value < min)
        return min;
    if (value > max)
        return max;
    return value;
}


void MyImage::applyKernel(std::vector<std::vector<int>> kernel)
{
    int index(0), tempx(0), tempy(0);
    int wr(0), wg(0), wb(0), wa(0), sum(0);
    auto newPixels = new sf::Uint8[this->size_y * this->size_x * 4];
    // Calculate the sum of the kernel
    for (int i = 0; i < kernel.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < kernel[i].size(); j++) {
            sum += kernel[i][j];
        }
    }


    for (int y = 0; y < this->size_y; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < this->size_x; x++) {
            /*
            Calculate weighted sum from kernel
            */
            wr = wg = wb = wa = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < kernel.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < kernel[i].size(); j++) {
                    /*
                    Calculates the coordinates of the kernel relative to the pixel we are changing
                    */
                    tempx = x + (j - floor(kernel[i].size() / 2));
                    tempy = y + (i - floor(kernel.size() / 2));
                    //std::cout << "kernel=(" << j << ", " << i << "), pixel=(" << x << ", " << y << ") tempPos=(" << tempx << ", " << tempy << ")\n";
                    /*
                    This code below should have the effect of mirroring the image in the case the kernel coordinate is out of bounds (along the edge of the image)
                    */
                    tempx = (tempx < 0) ? -1 * tempx : tempx;
                    tempy = (tempy < 0) ? -1 * tempy : tempy;
                    tempx = (tempx > this->size_x) ? x - (j - floor(kernel[i].size() / 2)) : tempx;
                    tempy = (tempy > this->size_y) ? y - (i - floor(kernel.size() / 2)) : tempy;
                    if (tempx >= 0 && tempx < this->size_x && tempy >= 0 && tempy < this->size_y) {
                        index = (((tempy * this->size_x) - tempy) + (tempx)) * 4;
                        wr += kernel[i][j] * this->pixels[index];
                        wg += kernel[i][j] * this->pixels[index + 1];
                        wb += kernel[i][j] * this->pixels[index + 2];
                        wa += kernel[i][j] * this->pixels[index + 3];
                    }
                }
            }
            if (sum) {
                wr /= sum;
                wg /= sum;
                wb /= sum;
                wa /= sum;
            }
            index = (((y * this->size_x) - y) + (x)) * 4;
            newPixels[index] = clamp(wr, 0, 255);           // Red
            newPixels[index + 1] = clamp(wg, 0, 255);       // Green
            newPixels[index + 2] = clamp(wb, 0, 255);       // Blue
            newPixels[index + 3] = clamp(wa, 0, 255);       // Alpha
        }
    }
    this->pixels = newPixels;

    // Copies the data from our sf::Uint8 array to the image object to be displayed => Removes the overhead of calling setPixel(x,y,color) for every pixel {As a side note setPixel() should always be avoided}|
    this->im->create(this->size_x, this->size_y, this->pixels);
}
```

I was trying to use [-1,-1,-1], [-1,8,-1]. [-1,-1,-1] for edge detection but just ended up with a white image except for some pixels near the bottom. I've tried different images and kernels out but any that add to 0 don't work. For example if I take the edge detection kernel above and change the 8 to a 9, it gives an expected result. Is there something wrong with my idea of how convolution kernels work or is it just a bug in my code?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to divide the convolution sum by the total weight.  I don't see this happening in your code.  It would probably be useful to show your `clamp` function too.

Comment: I'm saying this happens when the sum is 0. the clamp function clamps a value between 0 and 255. and my idea for this at least is rather than having my code handle dividing by the sum, I would just include it in the kernel when I make it.

Comment: You asked if there is a bug.  I'm suggesting that we can't really know if there's a bug in your clamp function, since its parameters appear to be `double` and `int` types and you're assigning the result to a `uint8`.  A negative value being converted to `unsigned` might result in white pixels, assuming that white in this case is 255.  If you're convolving with double values, the total weight should normally add up to 1.0.  Here you are mixing together fast methods of kernels built for integer arithmetic, but using slow double arithmetic.  It's causing extra confusion.

Comment: Using just integers didn't fix the problem. for the exact code of clamp, it just checks if the number is less than 0 return 0 and if its greater than 255 return 255.

Comment: Well, in my opinion you should choose one strategy, not a mix.  Also, _vector-of-vector_ is not a great choice structure for a convolution filter.  Use contiguous memory to maximize chances of it remaining in cache.  You still haven't posted your `clamp` function.

Comment: added the clamp function and updated the original function

Comment: `kernel[i].size() / 2` is an integer, calling `floor` on it is superfluous. What is the reason you are writing your own convolution code? If this is for learning, then fine, but otherwise you should really consider using one of the many libraries that does this for you.

Comment: its for learning. And I didn't know that an integer divided by 2 always rounds down, thank you.